# How do I use Light on a Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, light

I have a custom user control, and I'd like to add some light effects to the custom control. I was trying to go for a light to "sweep" the control when the mouse enters the control. But I'm slightly lost as to how to use WPF lights. I can use them on custom geometry I define, but I can't seem to get them to work on standard controls.

This is my xaml code for the custom control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="CActionTile" x:Class="App.ActionTile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App" Background="{DynamicResource ActionTileBackgroundBrush}"
             BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5" BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="80" d:DesignWidth="388">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Run FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="28"
                 Foreground="{DynamicResource ActionLabelBrush}" Text="{Binding Label, ElementName=CActionTile}" />
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="12"
                 Foreground="{DynamicResource ActionSubLabelBrush}" Text="{Binding SubLabel, ElementName=CActionTile}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <!-- This is where I'm kinda stuck... not sure what to do from here... -->
        <Viewport3D x:Name="vp1">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera LookDirection="0,0,-1" Position="0,0,5" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <AmbientLight Color="White" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Basically I'm trying to get this UWP Composition effect (https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/TextShimmer) to work in my WPF application. I'm pretty sure I can figure out the sweep effect when the pointer enters the control, but I need some help getting light effects to show on the controls themselves.